# Eloquent query get both tables using Find()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get all columns from 2 tables using eloquent.

So far I can only get the info from one.

This are my 2 models :

Clase model

```
public function courses() {
    return $this->hasMany('Course');
}
```

A class has many courses

Course Model

```
 public function clase() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Clase','Clase_id');
}
```

The Course table has Clase_id to link them

If I run this query

```
Clase::find(2)->courses;
```

It searches courses table clase_id = 2 and returns all columns

But how do I get the clase columns too??

**Update**

If I run this :

```
$values = course::with('clase')->find(3);
```

I get this array :

```
{"id":3,"course":"Essay June","desc":"English Essay for potentiL KD DK NVER ","points":10,"Clase_id":2,"active":0,"clase":{"id":2,"Year":"1","Name":"English","user_id":1}}
```

So Clase_id = 2 and Clase.id = 2 ,they are linked.
But my query searches for Courses.id and it needs to search Clase_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already did, just use it;

```
$clase = Clase::find(2);

$courses = $clase->courses;
```

If you want all columns together for some reason, then use joins, but I doubt you really do.

Comment: Hi, It doesnt return the columns from the clase table.

Comment: Of course it does. You know what ORM is? `$clase` is row from `clase` table, `$clase->courses` is a collection of rows from `courses` table. All wrapped in Eloquent models. Of course as long as your setup is correct (`$table`, $primaryKey` etc - check the docs if you're not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Clase::find(2)->courses()->get();
```

OR

```
Clase::where('id', '=', 2)->courses()->get();
```

Let me know if that does the trick.

In hindsight... I suppose this does exactly the same thing as OP's query now doesn't it. Misread the question. Should be like so:

```
$clases = Clase::find(2)->courses();
```

Then read the courses/clases as usual:

```
foreach($clases AS $clase){
  echo $clase->column_name;
}
```

Comment: Well, your 2nd piece is wrong - you cannot chain query with relation, and 3rd piece returns `Relation` object, so you can't provide it to the foreach, for it hasn't been yet executed.

Comment: It didnt work it still gives me just courses table. I made an upate with with() that works but it searches for ID no Clase ID